# Get expiration date related on date

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to calculate IsExpired in model if date is in past, but I need to check till 23: 59:59

So for example if expiry date is 2021-06-02 13:56:22  and today is 2021-06-03 13:56:22

Date will be expired

And if expiry date is 2021-06-03 13:56:22 and today is 2021-06-03 it will not be expired, because it's still not 2021-06-03

I wrote this code, but it's not working

```
 public bool IsExpired => ExpirationDate > DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Trim() + " 23:59:59");
```

How I can make it work?

Comment: Do you mean you want `ExpirationDate.Date < DateTime.Now.Date`? So it will be epxired if the day of `ExpirationDate` is before today?

Comment: Yes. that's it! @Llama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have `IsExpired` be true if the day of expiration is before today, you probably just want this:

```
public bool IsExpired => ExpirationDate.Date < DateTime.Now.Date;
```

The `.Date` part zeroes the time, so we do it to both to ensure that it's at the start of the day for both.

Taking your example of 2021-06-03 13:56:22 and 2021-06-03 00:00:00, we'd end up with the following comparison:

```
2021-06-03 < 2021-06-03 = false // not expired
```

P.S. If you want to include today in "expired", then you should change `<` to `<=`.